# c# eliminatig over spaces in richtextbox output

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, string-formatting, richtextbox

I have some problems with  spaces, i don't know how to solve it. It should be like this:

[image]

But it's actually like this:

[image]

```
public void azurirajPodatke()
{
    richTextBox1.Clear();

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string kom = "select * from Pecaros order by PecarosID asc";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(kom, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string id = dr[0].ToString();             
            string ime = dr[1].ToString();                   
            string prezime = dr[2].ToString();                   
            string adresa = dr[3].ToString();                   
            string telefon = dr[4].ToString();                   
            string grad = dr[5].ToString();
            string linija = string.Format(
                "{0,-15}|{1,-10}|{2,-15}|{3,-15}|{4,30}|{5,-15}", 
                id, ime, prezime, adresa, telefon, grad);                   
            richTextBox1.Text += linija+"\n";                                          
        }

        dr.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Expected GUI is using a ListView while you have a RichTextbox

Comment: Use a fixed-width font

Comment: If you want to use RichTextBox only -- you will have to adjust spacing by first considering the longest text for each column and keeping that many spaces for the entire column. That is why we have controls like (ListView or Grid)

Comment: RichTextBox has a `SelectionTabs` Property, in the form of an array of integers expressing **Pixel** positions: `richTextBox1.SelectionTabs = new int[] { 50, 100, 200, (...) };` then set `richTextBox1.AcceptsTab = true;` and space your columns with `\t`.

Comment: @Jimi thank you it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to wrap all of the objects (textbox, labels, and etc) inside a groupBox object as shown in my image.  This will allow you to configure padding and margins to control the distance your objects are away from another.  Then, change the formBorderStyle to "FixedSingle" I would change the "MaximizeBox" to false.  Then, change the textbox to a ListView or DataGrid.  Finally, when you adjust the form size, it will rearrange the objects how you want them.

[image]

Comment: But OP's question is about the weird spacing he has in the RIchTextBox.

Comment: I covered that question in my answer too, and he needs to make several changes in order to make it look like he wants.  He needs to change the richtextbox to listview and then the entire form itself